# Como abrir o Waze e navegar por endereço

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iphone

Boa noite, pessoal

Como eu faço para abrir o Waze no app e setar o endereço via string (eu quero navegar direto pelo endereço, não por coordenadas)
No momento, estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
func showWazeNaviationWithUrl(_ strURL: String) {
    if let url = URL(string: "waze://") {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            if let url = URL(string: strURL) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        } else {
            //Waze is not installed. Launch AppStore to install Waze app
            if let url = URL.init(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/id323229106") {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
```

em outra classe que dispara este método, eu tenho o seguinte:

```
   func startNavigation(address: String) {

        var allowedQueryParamAndKey = NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        allowedQueryParamAndKey.remove(charactersIn: ";/?:@&=+$, ")
        let _address = address.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedQueryParamAndKey)

        let strURL = String(format: "https://waze.com/ul?ll=%@&navigate=yes", _address!)
        self.delegate?.showWazeNaviationWithUrl(strURL)
    }
```

Apos tudo isso ser executado, o app abre porém, ele não abre a janela de navegação... Apenas fica parado no mapa.

A minha String com o endereço fica da seguinte forma:

```
"https://waze.com/ul?ll=R%20VISCONDE%20DE%20URUGUAI%20%2C%20311%20%20-%20CENTRONiter%C3%B3i%20-%20RJ&navigate=yes"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente, a sua URL Query está errada. Olhando a documentação do [Waze](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/), é possível verificar que você está usando o parâmetro `?ll=...` ao invés do `?q=...`, ou seja, você está procurando através de um parâmetro de Latitude e Longitude um endereço.

Sendo assim, para procurar no parâmetro correto (Um endereço em um endereço), você deve substituir a seguinte linha:

```
let strURL = String(format: "https://waze.com/ul?ll=%@&navigate=yes", _address!)
```

por:

```
let strURL = String(format: "https://waze.com/ul?q=%@&navigate=yes", _address!)
```

Além disso, pude observar que o endereço que você passa as vezes não encontra resultado, como no exemplo a baixo, onde você procura:

```
R VISCONDE DE URUGUAI , 311  - CENTRONiterói - RJ
```

Se você verificar, o bairro e cidade estão juntos, fazendo com que não apareçam resultados. O teste que fiz foi trocando a URL para o parâmetro `?q=` e com o seguinte endereço:

```
R VISCONDE DE URUGUAI , 311 Niterói
```

Com essas alterações, você começará a ter resultados corretos na integração entre o seu aplicativo e o Waze.

Answer (score 1):

Se você fizer a compilação usando o iOS SDK 9.0 e versões mais recentes, será preciso adicionar o seguinte código ao arquivo Info.plist do seu aplicativo para incluir o Waze:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>waze</string>
</array>
```

O exemplo de código a seguir navegará até a latitude/longitude se o Waze estiver instalado. Caso contrário, a app store da Apple será aberta para que o usuário instale o aplicativo:

```
- (void) navigateToLatitude:(double)latitude longitude:(double)longitude
{
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]
    canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"waze://"]]) {
      // O Waze está instalado. Inicia o Waze e a navegação com base na latitude e longitude
      NSString *urlStr =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://waze.com/ul?ll=%f,%f&navigate=yes",
        latitude, longitude];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
  } else {
    // O Waze não está instalado. Inicia a AppStore para instalar o Waze
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL
      URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106"]];
  }
}
```

Caso precise converter um endereço para latitude e longitude, use o CoreLocation como no exemplo abaixo:

```
import CoreLocation

var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.geocodeAddressString("Seu endereço") {
    placemarks, error in
    let placemark = placemarks?.first
    let latitude = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude
    print("Lat: \(latitude), Lon: \(longitude)")
}
```